# How to solely keep the lowest value of a variable for each observation?

Tags: sas

Hopefully this is a rather simple problem, unfortunately I haven't been able to crack the problem yet. I have a dataset of several companies containing a variable indicating when the company stops its activities. Unfortunately this dataset has been updated each year without adjusting any previous years, and as a consequence the actual year of exit/stop only enters once. Take for example company 1 in the table below. The company exits in 2010 but in each year leading up to 2010 a dummy ("9999") for still active is written instead. For company 1, I would like to replace this "9999" by "2010" (i.e. the year of exit) while leaving the "9999" for companies that are still active at the end of the period such as company 3.

```
company          year      exit/stop year
company 1        2007      9999 
company 1        2008      9999
company 1        2009      9999
company 1        2010      9999
company 2        2007      9999
compnay 2        2008      9999
company 2        2009      2009
company 3        2007      9999
company 3        2008      9999
company 3        2009      9999
company 3        2010      9999
company 4        2007      9999
company 4        2008      2008
...              ...       ...
```

I have tried to find the lowest value for each company and replace all values in "EXIT/STOP YEAR" by the lowest value, but so far it have not worked properly so I was wondering if anyone might have an idea of how to do this operation?

Bests,

Comment: What is the difference between company 1 and company 3?  Perhaps you meant to talk about company 2 in your question?  That one has an exit value that is not 9999 on the last record.

Comment: Do you just want to change the EXIT values for all of the records to have the value from the last record for that company?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but company 1 was meant to exit in 2010 so that it should be 2010 instead of 9999 for company 1. I would like to end up with a dataset where all exit values for company 1 says 2010, all exit values for company 4 that says 2008 and all exit values for company 2 should be 2009.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just take the last record and merge it back onto the data. Or it is even easier to just take the records that are not 9999 and merge them back on.

```
data have ;
  input company &:$20. year exit ;
cards;
company 2    2007  9999
company 2    2008  9999
company 2    2009  2009
company 3    2007  9999
company 3    2008  9999
company 3    2009  9999
company 3    2010  9999
company 4    2007  9999
company 4    2008  2008
;
data want ;
  merge have 
        have(keep=company exit rename=(exit=final) 
             where=(final ne 9999) )
  ;
  by company ;
  exit = coalesce(final,exit);
run;
```

[image]